# PYTHON - How can I go about retrying an API call only once, if it fails?

Tags: python, api, rest, error-handling, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to write a function my_func, which gets data from an API from 1 page. my_func is called in a loop in another function. While it works successfully, I'm having a hard time determining if my error handling is proper.

The issue is that, I'm looping through 2000+ pages. So, I don't want 1 pages error to cause everything to fail. When my code fails, I have it set to rollback changes. The changes being adding the new data to the Redshift table.

```
import requests as r
import time

def my_func(api_key, page):

    base_url = f'https://example.com/api/?limit=1000&page={page}'

    headers = {'Authorization': f"{api_key}", 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}  

    try:
        response = r.get(url=base_url, headers=headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to get data from API: {e}")
    else:
        #If unsuccessful API call, sleep 2 seconds and try again
        if response.status_code != 200:
            time.sleep(2)
            response = r.get(url=base_url, headers=headers)

             #If 2nd unsuccessful API call, print status message and pass
            if response.status_code != 200:
                print(f"Status code {response.status_code} \n Failed to get data from API on page {page}")
                pass #return None, None
            #If 2nd API call is successful, save data to dictionary as a tuple
            else:
                dict1 = response.json()['dict1']
                dict2 = response.json()['dict2']
                return dict1, dict2
        #If successful API call, save data to dictionary as a tuple
        else:
            dict1 = response.json()['dict1']
            dict2 = response.json()['dict2']
            return dict1, dict2
```

#### **This piece if the code is my main concern:**

```
if response.status_code != 200:
  print(f"Status code {response.status_code} \n Failed to get data from API on page {page}")
  pass #return None, None
```

I just need to know if this code reads and performs the way I'm think it should.

Try to get the response

exception: print message

no exception: print message

if bad API call: sleep and try again
if 2nd API call bad: print message and pass (should I pass or return None, None?)

else 2nd API call good: save dicts as a tuple and return tuple

else good API call: save dicts as a tuple and return tuple

Comment: check out `urllib3.util.retry.Retry` used in conjunction with `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter`.  If that does not get you unstuck let me know and I will post the code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library [tenacity](https://github.com/jd/tenacity). It can solve your problem plus much more like increase number of retries, retry based on exception or result, etc